# Angular js - Fix headers of table

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to fix the headers of a table . I have tried all the solutions from a web . But Nothing is working for me . So , My code is like

```
<div class="report-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"
            ng-class="updatingReportFieldValue ? 'table-container-disabled cursor-progress' : ''"
            ng-show="!loadingReports">
            <div class="suggestion">
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-header-fixed fixed_headers">
                <thead class="text-center text-info">
                  <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Annotation</th>
                <th class="text-center">Field</th>
                <th class="text-center">Message</th>
                <th class="text-center">Score</th>
                <tr>
                </thead>
                <tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.annotation }}</td>
                  <td class="td-report-field">{{ report.attributes.field }}</td>
                  <td>{{ report.attributes.message }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.score }}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
```

IN css I am not doing anything  just ,

```
.report-container{



}
```

So , I tried different solutions , But I was facing the problem of

```
align the header to the table columns
```

.So , How can i solve this problems ? Any help will be appreciated ..

Comment: Have you considered fixing width for each column? Either in `px` or `%`

Comment: Yes , But My data in table always changes. It's not same .

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex. its super simple.

Here is an example. All you need to change is on ng-repeat instead of hard coded td values.

```css
table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
}
tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
}
th,
td {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  text-align: center;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+1)>td {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
thead th {
  color: white;
  background-color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<div class="suggestion">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-header-fixed fixed_headers">
    <thead class="text-center text-info">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Annotation</th>
        <th class="text-center">Field</th>
        <th class="text-center">Message</th>
        <th class="text-center">Score</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Annotation
        </td>
        <td>Field
        </td>
        <td>Message
        </td>
        <td>1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

You need to adjust the flex values according to your needs. modified the snippet to have different column widths.

```css
table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.report-annotation {
  flex: 1;
}
.report-field {
  flex: 0.5;
}
.report-message {
  flex: 2;
}
.report-score {
  flex: 0.4;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+1)>td {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
thead th {
  color: white;
  background-color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<div class="suggestion">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-header-fixed fixed_headers">
    <thead class="text-center text-info">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center report-annotation">Annotation</th>
        <th class="report-field">Field</th>
        <th class="text-center report-message">Message</th>
        <th class="text-center report-score">Score</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="report-annotation">Annotation
        </td>
        <td class=" report-field">Field
        </td>
        <td class=" report-message">Message
        </td>
        <td class="report-score">1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
        <td class="text-center report-annotation">{{annotation }}</td>
        <td class="report-field">{{field }}</td>
        <td class="report-message">{{message }}</td>
        <td class="text-center report-score">{{ score }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: All my td values are different , Meanes they are like                                                     <tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.annotation }}</td>
                  <td class="td-report-field">{{ report.attributes.field }}</td>
                  <td>{{ report.attributes.message }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.score }}</td>
                </tr>

Comment: this solution is not working for me , If I increase the height of table then it's giving me one more scrollbar on y axis .

Comment: second scroll bar is due to the SO's code snippets width, check this in full view and you shouldn't run into the double scroll bar issue

Comment: okay  , But   
align the header to the table columns is not solved in this code .I am talking about tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
}   this height.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean here. I see the header column and content value columns align. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: The line after header name annotation is not aligned to the annotation column . In short , Horizontal and vertical lines are not proper .

Comment: I see it aligned properly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WIYk.png. I m not sure, if you referring dotted border as not aligned.

Comment: Sorry but , depending upon the row data size , it is changing size of the row ,.

Comment: Isn't that expected? However it is really difficult to say why and how to solve it without seeing the data. As I mentioned you could start with this on fixed headers and build on top of it as per your requirement